# When to use a bootstrap in MLE

Tags: multivariate-analysis, maximum-likelihood, bootstrap

Suppose I have a data set of $n$ observations with the dependent variable sample $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, and independent variable sample $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}$ such that

$$\mathbf{Y} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{y}_1\\\mathbf{y}_2\\\vdots\\\mathbf{y}_n\end{pmatrix}\;
\mathbf{X} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1\\\mathbf{x}_2\\\vdots\\\mathbf{x}_n\end{pmatrix}
$$
I wish to model the following set of simultaneous equations for $i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$.

$$y_{i,1} = f_1(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{y}_i, \beta_{1}) + \varepsilon_{i,1}$$
$$y_{i,2} = f_2(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{y}_i,\beta_{2}) + \varepsilon_{i,2}$$
$$...$$
$$y_{i,k} = f_k(\mathbf{x}_{i},\mathbf{y}_i,\beta_{k}) + \varepsilon_{i,k}$$

For pre-specified $f_j$ and unknown parameter vectors $\beta_j$, $j \in \{1,\cdots,k\}$.

I choose to solve this problem using MLE under the assumption that

$$
\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon_1\\\varepsilon_2\\\vdots\\\varepsilon_n\end{pmatrix}\;\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}) 
$$
where $ \mathbf{\Sigma}$ is unknown.

So I wish to maximize the likelihood function in respect to the inputs $$\hat{\beta}_1,\cdots,\hat{\beta}_{k},\;and\;\mathbf{T}$$
where $\mathbf{T}$ is a lower triangular matrix such that $\mathbf{TT^{'}=\hat{\Sigma}}$ (this is done to avoid computationally expensive constraints on $\mathbf{\hat{\Sigma}}$ during numerical optimization).

In such models would there ever be a reason for using a bootstrap rather than the likelihood hessian to approximate standard error of $\hat{\beta}_1,\cdots,\hat{\beta}_{k}$.  I would think both approximations of standard error to be the same assuming proper model specification.  Is that true?  Sometimes I find the 2 methods differ drastically even when I'm certain I'm correctly specified.

For parameters like $\mathbf{\Sigma}$, I feel obligated to do a bootstrap since the elements of $\mathbf{\hat{\Sigma}}$ are non-linear (quadratic) functions of the elements of $\mathbf{T}$.  But this can be computationally expensive.  Is it worthwhile to derive, parametrically, a limiting distribution and confidence interval for these type of parameters, or am I better off just letting my computer run all night to bootstrap a confidence interval?